# Does bash calls `execve()` without making further change to how `execve()` treats the signal dispositions?

Tags: linux, bash, exec

Bash manual says

> When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be executed, 
>   ...
>    traps caught by the shell are reset to **the values inherited from the shell’s parent**, and
>   traps ignored by the shell are ignored

[execve() manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) says

> During an execve(2), the dispositions of handled signals are reset to **the default**; the dispositions of ignored signals are left unchanged."

Are "the default" and "the values inherited from the shell’s parent" the same?

Does bash calls `execve()` without making further change to how `execve()` treats the signal dispositions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, "the default" and "the values inherited from the shell’s parent" are not the same. In execve's case, "the default" refers to `SIG_DFL`, which causes the default action as specified by [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). In bash's case, "the values inherited from the shell’s parent" means exactly what it says; if such a signal was ignored (`SIG_IGN`) by its parent, it will be ignored in its child too.

A key to understanding what's going on here is the word "handled". It refers to a custom signal handler function, distinct from either `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`. It must be reset by execve, as the new process won't have the signal handler function that the old process used.

Note that newer versions of the execve manpage refer to the "handled" signals as "caught" signals, to be in line with the terminology used by the rest of Linux. This is still distinct from both default and ignored signals.

Simple version: if either bash or bash's parent had a signal marked as `SIG_IGN`, it will be `SIG_IGN` in the new child too. Otherwise, it will be `SIG_DFL` in the new child. It can never be a handler in the new child, since no handler from bash or its parent will exist in the new child.